# C - How scanf inputs work and how it iterates in loops?

Tags: c, loops, input, scanf

I know the basics of scanf(); requiring a conversion specifier % and an address to the variable to store the input value &.

While doing an assignment, there was a task that involved inputting an arbitrary number of values, one example would be:
5 4 3 2 1

Into scanf, and then print out number of symbols corresponding to the integer typed (eg. '?'), so it would display the terminal as:

```
5 4 3 2 1
?????
????
???
??
?
```

In this case I had put the scanf in a while loop as so:

```
int i, num;
while(scanf("%d",&num)==1){
   printf("%d",num);
   for (i=0; i<num; i++){
      printf("?");
   }
   printf("/n");
}
```

I am totally confused how scanf reads multiple integers in one input line (5 4 3 2 1) when many sources has specified that scanf only takes one integer until it reads a whitespace. From looking at this, my understanding is that the whitespace separating the integers indicate a new iteration following the previous integer?
When I tried to trace how printing works, it printed as:

```
5 4 3 2 1
5?????
4????
3???
2??
1?
```

...So my question is how does scanf 'save' all these integers in one line to 'num' and print EACH of the corresponding symbols to the values given AFTER input? Wouldn't integers be replacing the previous in the variable without an array?

Sorry if this question does not make sense - still quite new to coding. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding of `scanf` is true, scanf only takes one integer until it reads a whitespace.

What makes you confused here is how the algorithm works. Your algorithm first reads the integer 5 and prints "immediately" five `?`. It continues to read 4, print four `?`, read 3, print three `?`, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

> Wouldn't integers be replacing the previous in the variable without an array?

There's no array required here at all.

The `scanf()` function takes the value (assuming white spaces included) and all of them are saved one by one into the variable `num`. If you use a debugger (suppose using GDB) and set a breakpoint in `while()`, you'll get to know by stepping into that the variable `num` is changed in each iteration and the `for` loop runs till `num` is reached.

An example of two iterations using a debugger is provided below (focus on `num` on the left corner):

**Iteration 1:**

[image: Iteration 1]

**Iteration 2:**

[image: Iteration 2]

Answer (score 0):

`scanf` 'reads' characters from the standard input stream `stdin` (if there is nothing there yet it prompts the user to type something to be added to it), and converts them to a format depending on the conversion specifiers used in the format string.

You can think about `stdin` as a sequence of characters in the memory, and every time the user types something in the terminal and presses Enter what was typed is added to the `stdin`.

So in your case, when you type `5 4 3 2 1` and presses Enter in the terminal, `stdin` will receive the sequence of characters `"5 4 3 2 1\n"` (notice that the new line character was added when you pressed Enter).

Then the `scanf("%d",&num)`, which is expecting only 1 decimal integer number, 'reads' and 'consumes' from `stdin` the relevant characters that form one continuous decimal integer number.

In this case `5` is read the first time `scanf` is executed, and `" 4 3 2 1\n"` is left in the `stdin`. Then as the condition is satisfied the loop statements are executed. And the second time `scanf` is executed the leading space is discarded by the `%d` specifier and `4` is read, leaving `" 3 2 1\n"` in the `stdin`. And so on until no decimal integers numbers can be read from the `stdin`...